# Is $\mathfrak{c}E$ a $C$-module for an abelian ring $C$ and an ideal $\mathfrak{c}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $C$ be an abelian ring, $\mathfrak{c}$ an ideal of $C$ and $E$ a $C$-module. Let $\mathfrak{c}E$ be the sub-$\mathbf{Z}$-module of $E$ generated by the family $(c x)_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}$ of elements of $E$: i.e.
$$\mathfrak{c}E=\left\{y\ |\ (\exists\mu)\left(\mu\in\mathbf{Z}^{(\mathfrak{c}\times E)}\ \land\ y=\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}(cx)\right)\right\}.$$

I would like to show that $\mathfrak{c}E$ is stable under the action of $C$. Let $\lambda\in C$ and $y\in\mathfrak{c}E$: there exists $\mu\in\mathbf{Z}^{(\mathfrak{c}\times E)}$ such that $y=\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}(cx)$. Then
$$\lambda y=\lambda\left(\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}(cx)\right)=\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\lambda\mu_{cx}(cx)=\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}\lambda(cx)=\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}(\lambda c)x.$$
Obviously $\lambda c\in\mathfrak{c}$ for $c\in\mathfrak{c}$. I am not able to rewrite the sum $\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}(\lambda c)x$ in a form that will allow me to conclude that $\lambda y\in\mathfrak{c}E$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Elements of the form $\lambda c$ make up a subset of the set of elements of the form $c$ for $c \in \mathfrak c$. For any $d \in \mathfrak c$ not of this form, $\mu_{dx} = 0$ for any $x \in E$. That is all you need. Alternatively use commutativity: $\lambda(cx) = c(\lambda x)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The trouble is that indices and the expressions appearing in the non-$\mathbf{Z}$-coefficient part of the sum need to be the same. The sum $\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}c(\lambda x)$ is indexed by $(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E$ but the expressions are of the form $\mu_{cx}c(\lambda x)$. So $\lambda$ appears in the summand but not in the index. This prevents the sum to have the form specified by the defintion of $\mathfrak{c}E$.

Comment: Can I assert that $\sum_{(c,x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{cx}c(\lambda x)=\sum_{(c,\lambda x)\in\mathfrak{c}\times E}\mu_{c(\lambda x)}c(\lambda x)$?